# How to let the radio button select checked when the checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I wan to let the radio button select checked after all the checkboxs are unchecked, but now it doesn't work when I deselect all the checkboxs.Help!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function uncheck(radio,checkbox){
         var fliter_checkbox=$(checkbox);
             var fliter_radio=$(radio);

         fliter_checkbox.click(function(){
                fliter_checkbox.each(function(){
                   fliter_radio.attr("checked",false);
                   if(fliter_checkbox.attr("checked")==false){
                      fliter_radio.attr("checked",true);
                   }
                })
         })

         fliter_radio.click(function(){
                fliter_radio.each(function(){
                  fliter_checkbox.attr("checked",false);
                })
         })
     }

        uncheck('#fliter input[name="vendor_all"]','#fliter input[name="vendor"]');

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Radios and Checkboxes use checked="checked" instead of true and false. Instead of setting checked to false, you need to removed the checked attribute like this:

```
fliter_checkbox.removeAttr("checked");
```

Also, instead of checking that the attribute is false, you need to test that the attribute exists:

```
if(fliter_checkbox.attr("checked") !== 'undefined')...
```